# Does "to make a bed" mean "to prepare the bed sheets etc" only?

Tags: idioms

I know that "**to make a bed**" means "*to prepare, arrange the bed sheets for sleeping in the bed*". But what about "*constructing*" and "*assembling*" a bed, say, by a carpenter? Is it alright to say "*I work as a carpenter. I **make** beds and tables*" or should I use another phrase/verb?

Comment: If you say *I make beds and tables* it should be fairly clear. But were you to say *I make beds for a living* you could just as easily be taken for a chambermaid as a carpenter.

Comment: Simply switching tables and beds would remove some of the ambiguity..."I make tables and beds and other furniture."  You can also change the verb to "build", "construct", etc.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez -- Right, although I'd think it would be more graceful to use the serial comma in that case -- "tables, beds, and other furniture..."

Comment: Absent any contextual clues to the contrary, any US English speaker would interpret "make a bed" to mean fix up the sheets, pillows, and blankets neatly on the bed.  Any other use of "make" (for tables, automobiles, chewing gum, etc) would imply participating in the manufacture of said item.  And "construct" does not carry the same special-case connotation for beds as does "make".  "Assemble" would be a hair more ambiguous in the case of beds -- it could be taken either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Make a bed* is indeed ambiguous. But arranging the linen is a so much more common activity, within nearly everybody's daily concerns even if they don't do it themselves, that unless there is some specific context pushing it, the other meaning hardly occurs to us.